# Dealing with Spritesheets - resizing

Tags: java

Let's say that I have a spritesheet with 4 sprites (standing, breathing player).

When I load it with

```
player_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.player_standing);
```

it sets it's width and height to for example 100/50 and I have to divide it by 4 and I get four sprites 25x50.

Problem is here that when I switch the app to tablet (I was on phone) sprites have different sizes when loaded.

How to solve issues like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the pixel density for your phone and tablet are different.

If so a few of options are,

1) Have a set of spritesheets created for varying pixel density displays and pick the closest one that matches the pixel density it was created for. You could end up with a lot of spritesheets

2) Scale your sprites when you draw them.

You can use a mixture of both techniques.

If your phone has a pixel density of 100, and your tablet has a pixel density of 200, then your sprites would seem half the size on the tablet. In this case if you chose option 2 then you'd need to double the scale

You can find a handy PPI list for various devices [here](http://pixensity.com/list/phone/)